# just expand first match file name in tab completion of zsh

Tags: zsh

There are three files a.pdf, b.pdf, c.pdf, I want to use zsh as

```
xpdf *.pdf<tab>
# zsh will expand like
xpdf a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf
# I wish
xpdf a.pdf
b.pdf c.pdf   #<-- more other option could be select
```

1. I wish the <tab> could show a menu to let me select one of the files.
2. How to un-expand 'a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf' to '*.pdf', any hotkey?

If instead of **xpdf**, just for **ls -l**, how to let me choose one pdf file in **ls -l *.pdf**

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. `zsh` knows to complete pdf-files when completing for `xpdf`, so doing `xpdf <tab>` should do. If you always want menu completion use this style: `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select`. See `zshcompsys(1)` and search for `select=num` to find the relevant manual section.

Comment: Zsh accepts emacs shortcuts: to "undo", `Ctrl+x, u`. It will unexpand from 'a.pdf b.pdf c.pdf' to '*.pdf', like before you pressed tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `zsh-completions` installed, this should already work out of the box. ZSH has some smart completion routines that know what kinds of file extensions should be tab complete candidates for certain programs.

You can of course customize these using `zshcompctl`, but the example you give with `xpdf` usage should already be setup for you. The manual rule for this in an environment without the default completions installed would be something like this:

```
compctl -g "*.pdf" xpdf
```

That line in your `.zshrc` config file would add a new completion pattern for pdf files to the xpdf command.

Comment: in my .zshrc "autoload -Uz compinit", "compinit", I've tried your method, it display three pdf instead of one pdf file.